# Scraping data from interactive website map

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the **geolocations** from the 2 following websites:

1. **https://zendantenneskaart.omgeving.vlaanderen.be/** --> for this one, I found the underlying source json file, so it was easy https://www.mercator.vlaanderen.be/raadpleegdienstenmercatorpubliek/us/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=us:us_zndant_pnt&outputFormat=application/json
2. **http://www.sites.bipt.be/index.php?language=EN** --> for this one, I cannot find such a json file; moreover, I cannot find a way to scrape it using beautiful soup, since the visibility of the pins is dependent on the zoom of the map

Any ideas to scrape all the geo locations for the second website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use url `http://www.sites.bipt.be/ajaxinterface.php` and as latitude/longitude parameters specify some huge range. That way you get all data in one go.

For example:

```
import json
import requests
from html import unescape


url = 'http://www.sites.bipt.be/ajaxinterface.php'

data = {"action": "getSites",
 "latfrom": "-9999",
 "latto": "9999",
 "longfrom": "-9999",
 "longto": "9999",
 "LangSiteTable": "sitesfr"}


data = requests.post(url, data=data).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data[:10]: # <-- print only first 10 items
    print('{:<50}{:<50}{:<30}{:<40} {:.4f} {:.4f}'.format(d['Eigenaar1'], unescape(d['Locatie']), unescape(d['Adres']), unescape(d['PostcodeGemeente']), float(d['Longitude']), float(d['Latitude'])))

print()
print('Total items:', len(data))
```

Prints:

```
Orange Belgium: 203W1_2                           Cité de la Bruyère                                Clos des Marronniers 201      1480 Tubize                              4.2086 50.6810
Telenet: _AN0171A                                 Watertoren                                        Scheeveld                     2870 Puurs                               4.2718 51.0744
Telenet: _AN0235V                                                                                   E34                           2290 Vorselaar                           4.7578 51.2449
Orange Belgium: 148L1_6                           Institut Provincial d'Enseignement Supérieur      Rue du Commerce 14            4100 Seraing                             5.5077 50.6130
Orange Belgium: 198L1_5 / 32198L1_1 / 42198L1_1   Lieu-dit 'Bièster'                                Thier de Coo                  4970 Stavelot                            5.8876 50.3859
Telenet: _NR1363A                                                                                   Route de Sovenne              5560 Houyet                              4.9529 50.1997
Orange Belgium: 181R1_1                                                                             Route Rimbaut / Route Rimbaut 6890 Libin                               5.1504 49.9989
Proximus: 80WAM_00                                                                                  Rue de Hottleux 71            4950 Waimes                              6.0879 50.4152
Orange Belgium: 013R1_8                                                                             Rue Saint-Michel              6870 Saint-Hubert                        5.3666 50.0355
Proximus: 41BIA_00                                Aéroport de Bierset batiment 56                   Aérodrome                     4460 Grâce-Hollogne                      5.4584 50.6416

Total items: 8104
```